# using phaser.js with ionic2

Tags: javascript, html, ionic2, phaser-framework

I need a solution to integrate phaserjs with Ionic2.
Currently I have done

In index.html (ionic2)

```
<script src="js/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

IN page

```
game: any;
gameState:any;
elem: any;
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.elem = $("#gameContainer");
console.log($(this.elem).attr('class'));
this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO,this.elem);
this.gameState = {
  preload:function(){
    this.game.load.image('logo', 'img/appicon.png');
    console.log('preload');
  },
  create:function(){
    this.game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
    this.game.background = this.game.add.sprite(0,0,'background');
    console.log("hellow");
    var logo = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'logo');
    logo.anchor.setTo(0.5, 0.5);
  }
}
this.game.state.add('GameState',this.gameState);
this.game.state.start('GameState');
```

The canvas is not getting created in #gameContainer

Plz help

Comment: As far as I remember, Phaser doesn't create the canvas itself, have you tried to create the canvas by yourself then pass the canvas ID to phaser ?

Comment: 4th argument of Phaser.Game has the reference ot element where I want to embed the canvas. It works perfectly when uisng withotu Ionic, but not working with Ionic. Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO,this.elem)